# R - stat_compare_means return differnt value from Kruskal-Wallis test

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid, ggpubr, kruskal-wallis

I want to plot the p value of Kruskal-Wallis test to my `ggplot` using the R function `stat_compare_means` from the package `ggpubr`.

However, the plotted value is different from the value if I simply run the function:

> `kruskal.test(value ~ type, data = Profile_melt)`

my code to plot the p value is:

```r
ggplot(Profile_melt, aes(type, value)) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = factor(type), alpha = 0.5), 
               outlier.shape = NA, show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_jitter(width = 0.2, size = 2, show.legend = FALSE,
              aes(colour = factor(type)), alpha = 0.5) +
  theme_bw() +
  facet_grid(Case ~ Marker, scales = 'free') +
  stat_compare_means(comparison = list(c("Real", "Binomial")),method = 'kruskal.test')+
  background_grid(major = 'y', minor = "none") + # add thin horizontal lines 
  xlab('Category') +
  ylab('Cell counts (Frequencies)')+
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 15), 
        axis.title = element_text(size = 20), 
        legend.text = element_text(size = 38),
        legend.title = element_text(size = 30), 
        strip.background = element_rect(colour="black", fill="white"),
        strip.text = element_text(margin = margin(10, 10, 10, 10), size = 25)) +
  panel_border()
```

Here is my data [sample data](https://livejohnshopkins-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/hmi1_jh_edu/EeNrdh5npxFKj6GcnDoBgksB5WFssq4m5d46OyP5bwz0aw?e=mbCr8w)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many code lines which may not be relevant to the question. Perhaps, your question could be:

why does

```
kruskal.test(value ~ type, data = Profile_melt)

#Kruskal-Wallis chi-squared = 4.9673, df = 1, p-value = 0.02583
```

produce a different p value from

```
ggboxplot(Profile_melt, x="type", y = "value") + 
  stat_compare_means(comparison = list(c("Real", "Binomial")), method = 'kruskal.test')

# p-value = 0.49
```

You could work out the reason by checking original code. The developer of `ggpubr` may explain this better, and perhaps fix it there if it is an issue. To get correct and consistent p value, remove `comparison = list(c("Real", "Binomial"))`:

```
ggboxplot(Profile_melt, x="type", y = "value") + 
  stat_compare_means(method = 'kruskal.test')
```

or

#### Edit

```
ggboxplot(Profile_melt, x="type", y = "value") + 
  stat_compare_means(comparison = list(c("Real", "Binomial")))
```

With your other code, the graph looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Hi Zhiqiang, thank you for your reply. Remove this comparison = ... line do produce the consistent result, however, the format of the plot will also be altered, which is not what I want.

Comment: I see. You want to have the nice looking horizontal line. You can achieve that by remove `method = 'kruskal.test'` instead of `comparison = list(c("Real", "Binomial")`. I will revise my answer.

Comment: Please run the full codes that I provide. Your suggestion does not work when in facet.

Comment: I have run the code on my side. It works in the same way with `facet`, because you have small sample, it produces some warnings `cannot compute exact p-value with ties`. As I said, the real fix is perhaps to change `ggpubr`.

Comment: hummm that's werid...could you please provide the full codes on your side(with facet)? Thank you

Comment: I did not change any your other code, just removed either `comparison = list(c("Real", "Binomial"))` or `method = 'kruskal.test'`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204913/discussion-between-digipath-and-zhiqiang-wang).

Answer (score 1):

`stat_compare_means` from ggpubr calls `compare_means` which uses wilcox.test by default. So as @ZhiqiangWang pointed out, if you remove the method or the comparison it goes to the default which is similar to the p-value you got in the first place, because wilcoxon and kruskal for 2 sample are very similar:

```
kruskal.test(value ~ type, data = Profile_melt)
#Kruskal-Wallis chi-squared = 4.9673, df = 1, p-value = 0.02583
wilcox.test(value ~ type, data = Profile_melt)
#W = 1034939, p-value = 0.02583
```

Now, for the data you have, you most likely want a p-value for each of the separate case and marker, and not a pan comparison using `kruskal.test(value ~ type, data = Profile_melt)`. It doesn't make sense to print a same p-value for all the facets.

We first check the p-values we need:

```
compare_means(value ~ type, Profile_melt, group.by = c("Case","Marker"),
method="kruskal")
# A tibble: 30 x 8
   Case    Marker .y.            p   p.adj p.format p.signif method        
   <fct>   <fct>  <chr>      <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>    <chr>    <chr>         
 1 Case 1A CD3    value 0.000470   0.0085  0.00047  ***      Kruskal-Wallis
 2 Case 1A CD4    value 0.00000915 0.00022 9.2e-06  ****     Kruskal-Wallis
 3 Case 1A CD8    value 0.00695    0.09    0.00695  **       Kruskal-Wallis
 4 Case 1A CD20   value 0.707      1       0.70724  ns       Kruskal-Wallis
 5 Case 1A FoxP3  value 0.00102    0.014   0.00102  **       Kruskal-Wallis
 6 Case 1B CD3    value 0.0000415  0.00091 4.1e-05  ****     Kruskal-Wallis
```

which is similar to:

```
Profile_melt %>% 
group_by(Case,Marker) %>% 
summarize(k_p=kruskal.test(value ~ type)$p.value)

# A tibble: 30 x 3
# Groups:   Case [6]
   Case    Marker        k_p
   <fct>   <fct>       <dbl>
 1 Case 1A CD3    0.000470  
 2 Case 1A CD4    0.00000915
 3 Case 1A CD8    0.00695   
 4 Case 1A CD20   0.707     
 5 Case 1A FoxP3  0.00102
```

And we can plot, it's must easier to use the ggboxplot from ggpubr package:

```
p = ggboxplot(Profile_melt,x="type",y="value",add="jitter",
facet.by=c("Case","Marker"),scales="free_y",ggtheme=theme_pubclean())

p+stat_compare_means(
aes(label =paste("p=",scientific(as.numeric(..p.format..)))),
method="kruskal",size=2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! That's exactly what I want. Just one more thing, I want the horizontal compare line in each facet and I want to unify the number format to scientific notation (1.23e-3, etc). How could I do this?

Comment: I guess you mean the grid lines, for that you have to either choose a theme using the ggtheme option in ggboxplot, or you set it using + theme(..) . As for scientific, you can see what I have above, unfortunately ggpubr already has it at 1 significant figure, so I cannot do much about it

Comment: This is a bit outside the scope of your question, which is about p-values. So if you need a lot more tinkering with refining the plot, I would suggest you post it as a separate question..